Get Message ID with discord.js
I'm trying to make a discord suggestion system using mongodb. I want to add in the db the message id of the suggestyionbut I cannot fetch it. The suggestion is sent via the bot
I tried to do const msgID = interaction.message.id but it didn;t work anyone to help?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
